# Retention policy to aggregate several metrics with regular expression in graphite

Tags: time-series, graphite, retention

We are storing metrics having build number in the metric name. Here is the format of the metric in graphite.

```
latency.<host>.<request>.<buildNumber>.average
```

Issue with above format is that buildNumber is ever changing value and in our case it changes every week because of the release cycle. This results in new storage file(.wsp) every week and since whisper allocates space upfront, we never fully utilized the space because of changing build number.

I know disk space is cheap resource but still at some point I think we will have lot of unused space.

For e.g if each metric file is 10MB large and if we are sending 5000 different metrics for latency then for a particular build number we will use up 50GB. Now if every week we are sending a new build number then 1TB of disk space will get filled in 20 weeks which is roughly 5 months.(1TB = 1000GB)/(50GB per week) = 20 weeks

Above problem could be solved if we can aggregate multiple metrics in one of last month. Is there any way of specifying a retention policy where multiple metrics are merged in one using some aggregation method?

Or is there any way for tackling this kind of problem in graphite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Ceres storage engine for Graphite instead of using Whisper, you will avoid the problems of pre-allocation of space. https://github.com/graphite-project/ceres

I don't believe you can, during downsampling, merge multiple metrics with a specified aggregation. However, you can do this at the point of ingestion via aggregation-rules.conf. Documentation can be found here: http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config-carbon.html#aggregation-rules-conf

Comment: Thanks fourk for your answer. Ceres is a good option but it seems it doesn't good rollup functionality as of now.